# Loading view after login with Facebook in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

I'm beginner in iOS programming. I created an application which on the beginning user is logging-in with Facebook. After login, the app should display a second view where are information fetched from facebook: profile picture, age, name, etc.

But my is problem because after successfully logged I see the blanks: `UIImageView` is empty, which should have a profile picture, empty `UITextField`, which should have the name and age and non active `UISegmentControl`, which should indicate gender. In contrast view of all these data it appears only when I want to log off as a user of Facebook and I get alert asking if you really want to log out. At this point, in the background, I can see the view from all the data from Facebook. What is wrong? Any sugestions?

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
    //loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }
}

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

App.Delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FBSDKLoginButton class];
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
openURL:url                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication                                                     annotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: Read this tutorial this will help you. Link: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/

Comment: Thanks for link but there are solution for only one view. I'm working on storyboard and I have problem with communication between two controllers. On first controller I log and on the second I see a view with data from facebook.

Comment: Than you can save data in NSUserdefaults. its globel variable which allow you to access any where in application.